# Retrive only replacement template of regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

can i get only the substitution of the Regex.Replace?
Example.

```
String text = @"asdfgs sda gsa ga s
SECTOR:124 NAME:Ricko
asdfgs sda gsa ga s";
String regex = "^SECTOR:(\d+) NAME:(\w+)";
String substitution = "$2 $1";

String result = Regex.Replace(text, regex, substitution);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Normal result

```
asdfgs sda gsa ga s
Ricko 124
```

Wanted result

```
Ricko 124
```

Thaaaanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching all the characters around what you want to keep that should be deleted.

You could have the dot match a newline and using the multiline flag for the anchor.

```
(?sm).*?^SECTOR:(\d+) NAME:(\w+).*
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?sm)` Inline flags having the dot matching a newline and multiline
- `.*?` Match any character including a newline as least as possible
- `^` Start of string
- `SECTOR:(\d+) NAME:(\w+)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 1** for *SECTOR:* and capture 1+ word chars in **group 2** for *NAME:*
- `.*` Match the rest of the lines

Example

```
String text = @"asdfgs sda gsa ga s
SECTOR:124 NAME:Ricko
asdfgs sda gsa ga s";
String regex = @"(?sm).*?^SECTOR:(\d+) NAME:(\w+).*";
String substitution = "$2 $1";

String result = Regex.Replace(text, regex, substitution);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
Ricko 124
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Regex.Match` to extract the text and then concatenate Group 2 and Group 1 values:

```cs
Match m = Regex.Match(text, regex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
if (m.Success) {
    String result = $"{m.Groups[2].Value} {m.Groups[1].Value}";
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Awq6Pj).

Note:

- `RegexOptions.Multiline` is added since your string contains multiple lines, and you need to match start of a line with `^`
- `Regex.Match` returns the first match from the string
- `if (m.Success)` is used to check if there was a match with the given string and pattern
- `m.Groups[1].Value` contains the first capturing group value, `m.Groups[2].Value` contains the second capturing group value, etc.